# Batch file to copy only those file which contain particular string in second line of text

Tags: cmd

i want batch file which can  copy only those files which contain string like"VABJ" in second line of text in the txt files
source folder E:\text
destination folder D:\result

plz provide batch file for this

Answer (score -1):

Note, SO is not a free scripting service. But as it's relatively easy:

```
for %%a in (e:\text\*.txt) do (
  findstr /n "VABJ" "%%a" | findstr /b "2:" >nul && (
    copy "%%a" d:\result\
  )
)
```

Use a `for` loop to process each file.
Use `findstr /n` to search the string in a file.
Use `findstr /b "2:"` to filter for the second line.
When successful, copy the file.